# Pell-Type Diophantine Equation Solving using the method of ascent

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Can someone help me to prove there are infinitely many solutions to the Diophantine
equation: $$x^2 − 3y^2 = 1$$ using the method of ascent.
We can do this by showing how, given one solution $(u, v)$, we can compute another solution
$(w, z)$ that is larger is some suitable sense. Then my proof will involve finding a pair of
formulas, something like: $w = x + y$ and $z = x − y$.
However I tried these formulas and they don't work. So I asked my teacher and she said that there is a pair of second degree formulas which do work; one of them has a cross term and one of them involves the number 3.

Comment: How can the same thing 100 times to ask?  You especially don't read other topics?

Comment: @WillJagy It is not a duplicate because I want to prove using the method of Ascent.

Answer (score 1):

$(2x+3y)^2-3(x+2y)^2=x^2-3 y^2$

Comment: How did you get to that?

Comment: has this something to with the continued fraction of $\sqrt 3?$